# How to disable the automatic debugging mode in Matlab R2014a when encountering an error?

Tags: matlab, debugging

I would like to disable the automatic debugging mode.
There is a possibility to turn it on:
`dbstop if error` 
but I couldn't find a way to turn it off.
Anybody has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

As you already stated, you can use `dbstop if error` to automatically set a breakpoint and start debugging when an error occurs.

To clear breakpoints, you can use the function `dbclear`. The syntax to disable automatic breakpoints is almost identical:

```
dbclear if error
```